# Typecast string (cell value) to a user defined type?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm totally new to VBA.

I have created a user defined type called QualVal with two member variables. 
Then I've created several variables as Qualval and initialized its values.

Now I want to read a cell value, which is a string and match to the variable names and typecast it.

```
Type QualVal
    ul As Integer 'upper limit
    ll As Integer 'lower limit
End Type
```

My variables with type QualVal:

```
g1.ll = 94
g1.ul = 96
n.ll = 90
n.ul = 93
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
Dim group As QualVal
group = Cell(1, 2).Value 'would like to cast it to either g1 or n according to the cell value which also can only contain g1 or n
```

I hope it's clear what I want to do. 
I could use a select case statement but I have more variables than mentioned and this solution doesn't look nice.

Maybe someone can help me.

Thank you in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, but I'm not sure.

Anyhow the best solution that I can see is to store all possible variable names and their object in a Collection. Something like this:

```
Dim vars As New Collection

vars.Add "g1", g1
vars.Add "n", n

Dim group As QualVal
group = vars.Item(Cell(1, 2).Value)
```

This is also much safer because you have control of what variables that is exposed.

Comment: Thank you! 
But as soon as try to add a QualVal variable to the collection I get the following error:
Only user defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions

Comment: @TheLostOne: Hmm, I read abou this and found out that you can't store user defined types in collections, you have to make a class of it.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the late reply!
I've just used a simple Select Case statement in the end. 
Had problems with using a separate class and didn't hat the nerves and time any more. 
It was my first contact with VBA.